# Translating lat/lon coordinate on rotated/scaled maps

Tags: history, reprojection-mathematics

I need to indicate a lat/lon coordinate in an old map like this:
http://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/detail/RUMSEY~8~1~3017~90020003:Topographical-Map-Of-The-City-and-C

Projected on Google Maps:
http://rumsey.geogarage.com/maps/g2784000.html

I know the bounding box of the map as well as the dimensions of the image in pixels, but I couldn't figure out how to locate a lat/lon within this map.

Upper left is (40.698291,-74.079051), Lower Left (40.659855,-73.979638), Lower Right (40.855232,-73.835582) and Upper Right (40.882919,-73.940263).

Is there a standard formula on how to do locate a lot/lon datum in the historic map?